# Why is infinitary logic regarded as mysterious?

Tags: logic

I am looking for references to the "mysteriousness" of infinitary logic, preferably from people in the field, and even more preferably, with some kind of explanation as to why.

For example, is it that the semantics is underdetermined? Is it that the metaphysics is hard to conceive?

A reference without explanation would also be fine.

Comment: See [Infinitary Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-infinitary/) for details and biblio.

Comment: What is the source of your assertion about the "mysteriousness" of infinitary logic ?

Comment: It is just lesser known, and it involves more set theory than first-order (or even "basic second-order").

Comment: What metaphysics are you referring to in "the metaphysics is hard to conceive"?

Comment: @AsafKaragila What do you mean by "basic second-order"? Unless you're referring to Henkin semantics, I'd say it's far, far worse no matter how basic you go.

Comment: @Noah: Understanding second-order logic does not require you to consider cardinal arithmetic or large cardinals. Yes, they can pop up (e.g. supercompact and extendible cardinals are neatly tied to second-order logic), but you don't need to know these concepts to get a useful grasp of it. On the other hand, $\scr L_{\kappa,\lambda}$ requires you a better understanding of how cardinal arithmetic works if you want to actually utilize it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I mean, not for $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1\omega}$, and that's already got a very deep theory behind it (even with applications!).

Comment: @Noah: Sure, but that's the exception, definitely not the rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Infinitary formulas are inherently more complicated than finitary ones in various fundamental senses.

- Formulas in usual finitary first-order logic *(fine,in a countable language)* can be represented by natural numbers in a reasonable way; this is just [Godel numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering). Note that this is *more* than just being countable, I'm saying that the set of finitary formulas is "usefully countable." By contrast, the set of $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1\omega}$-formulas - this is the simplest infinitary logic - is uncountable. Each $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1\omega}$-formula can be reasonably represented by a *set of natural numbers*. But for a variety of reasons, $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is viewed as a much more mysterious object than $\mathbb{N}$. For example, there are $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1\omega}$-formulas which can't be "computably described!"
- Moving beyond the complexity of the logic as a *set*, the *deductive procedure* is also much weirder: compactness fails, and proofs are infinitary objects. Basically, infinitary logics don't have nearly as well-behaved a model theory or proof theory as classical first-order logic; ignoring philosophy, they're simply *more mathematically complicated* and harder to prove things about *(e.g. in lieu of compactness we have the much more technical [Barwise compactness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barwise_compactness_theorem))*. Also, as per the above paragraph, the complexity of (say) the set of infinitary validities is measured by [descriptive set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_set_theory) instead of, say, computability theory.
- Finally, when we pass to more complicated infinitary logics, things get even worse. Obviously, a $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_2\omega}$-formula is even harder to "describe" than a $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1\omega}$-formula. But it's even worse than when we allow infinitary *quantifiers*. $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1\omega_1}$ is the logic we get when we allow countable Boolean combinations *and* quantification over $\omega$-tuples (instead of just finitary quantification), and this is truly dreadful: e.g. we can (in an appropriate sense) express "the set of [constructible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe) reals is countable" as an $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1\omega_1}$-sentence, but this sentence's truth value is [set-theoretically dependent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_(mathematics)) in a very strong sense. So everything's bonkers.

Basically, *infinitary logic pushes us into set theory* to a degree which finitary logic doesn't. (Although [we shouldn't take the absoluteness of finitary first-order logic too blithely](http://jdh.hamkins.org/satisfaction-is-not-absolute/).)

Comment: How does one prove that the collection of all formulas for an infinitary logic (eg. $L_{\infty\omega}$) exists in ZFC?

Comment: @VioletFlame Replacement proves that $\mathcal{L}_{\kappa,\lambda}$ is a set for each $\kappa,\lambda$ (it's just a big ol' definition by recursion). The "logic" $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}$ (let alone $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\lambda}$ or $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\infty}$) is a proper class (and so not actually a logic per se, depending on what definition you use), but it's a "reasonably nicely definable" proper class so we can still refer to it.

Comment: Thanks, how to prove its a proper class? Also in $L_{\infty,\omega}$ we only have a countable amount of variables right?

Comment: @VioletFlame Well, it's closed under arbitrary-set-sized Boolean combinations, so there are $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}$-formulas of arbitrary size (e.g. $\forall x\bigwedge_{\eta<\omega_{17}}(x=x)$). So it has to be a proper class. For your second question, it depends on the presentation; usually the number of variables in $\mathcal{L}_{\kappa,\lambda}$ is $\lambda$, but this isn't always the case.

Comment: If you have more questions I suggest asking them separately, as opposed to in this comment thread.